# Calling Linux syscalls from C++ app code?

Tags: linux, memory, ubuntu, shared-memory

(Go easy- I am not a linux expert)

Is there anything stopping me from directly calling syscalls from a C++ application running on Linux?

I was interested in the following two "new" functions/features regarding sharing memory amongst processes:

http://lwn.net/Articles/405346/

Would I encounter security permissions like user/kernel mode on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in C++ that intrinsically stop you from "directly calling syscalls". You're already doing it, when you call `read()`, `write()`, `open()` and other syscalls.

As always, you have to be aware of permissions. From your own link:

> The current implementation does not use the flags argument. As would
>   be expected, copy_to_process() writes data into the target process's
>   address space. Either both processes must have the same ownership or
>   the copying process must have the CAP_SYS_PTRACE capability; otherwise
>   the copy will not be allowed.

So, you can certainly call these functions, but be aware that they may return with an error code, so make sure you have proper error handling in place. Of course, this assumes that your version of the kernel actually supports these syscalls. If you're new to Linux, it's probably beyond your abilities to apply the patch referenced in the article to your kernel.

Comment: I recommend against using bizarre syscalls (i.e. `copy_from_process` ...) which are not e.g. Posix standards are are not implemented in most kernels. There are more standard ways to share some memory between processes. Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/